# Class and substr in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="test-test-one">one</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="now" name="here_one"> <br />

<div class="test-test-two">two</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="now" name="here_two"> <br />

<div class="test-test-three">three</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="now" name="here_three"> <br />

<div class="test-test-four">four</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="now" name="here_four"> <br />
```

​
FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3eUEp/

I would like doing:

if i click on checkbox with name = **here_one** then this should be add class **.red** to div with class **test-test-one** 
and if i click on div with class **test-test-one**  then also should be checked checkbox with name = **here_one**.

How can  i make it with jQuery? i dont want use prev and next. I would like use selectors, but how to use substr from PHP for this?

Comment: Why not use `prev` and `next`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the javascript documentation : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/

And jQuery : http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

```
$('.now').click(function(){
    var v = $(this).attr('name').replace('here_', '');
if($(this).is(':checked'))  
{
        $('.test-test-'+v).addClass('red');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.test-test-'+v).removeClass('red');
    }
});


$("div[class^='test-test']").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('red'))
    {
        $(this).next('.now').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('red');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).next('.now').attr('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Btw: http://w3fools.com/. And you should deep-link to the documentation that the OP needs, not to general resources.

Comment: thanks, but if i click on div then this not checked checkbox

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.now').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this);  //the checkbox
    var numStr = elem.prop("name").split("_")[1];  //split the name into pieces
    $(".test-test-" + numStr).toggleClass("red", elem.is(":checked")); //get the element, toggle the class
});
```

[Edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eUEp/3/)

Now you shoudl not be using divs, you should be using labels. Clicking on a label will do what you want. There is no JavaScript needed.

```
<label class="test-test-one" for="foo1">one</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="now" name="here_one" id="foo1"> <br />
```

And when you use a label, you are doing people a service that are using screen readers.

Comment: thanks, but if i click on div then this not checked checkbox

Comment: As I said, you should be using a label and not a div. I did not code the div version since it is basically the same exact code as the checkbox. Change the selector to `div[class^=test-test-]` and add a line to check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any PHP for that, JS itself has a [`substr` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

```
$(function() {
    $("input.now").change(function(e) {
        var div = $("div.test-test-"+this.name.substr(5));
        if (this.checked)
           div.addClass("red");
        else
           div.removeClass("red");
    });
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/kTASS/))

Comment: thanks, but if i click on div then this not checked checkebox

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[class^=test-test-]").click(
    function ()
    {
        var sub = ($(this).attr("class")).substring(10);
        $(".now[name=here_"+sub+"]").attr("checked",true);
    }
    );

$(".now").click(
     function ()
    {
        var sub = ($(this).attr("name")).substring(5);
        alert(sub);
        $(".test-test-"+sub).addClass("red");
    }
    );
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.now').click(function(){
  var name_part = $(this).prop('name').split('_')[1];

  if($(this).is(':checked')){

    $('div[class$='+name_part+']').css('color', '#F00');

  }else{

    $('div[class$='+name_part+']').css('color', '#000');  

  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but if i click on div then this not checked checkbox